# How the trick is to take a picture in the database and then bring dipicturebox

Tags: c#, sql-server

[image: TB_FIX (Debugging)]

```
private void btnCARI_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        tes.Open();
        SqlCommand cmdSelect = new SqlCommand("SELECT gambar FROM tblBARANG WHERE id= '" + txtCARI.Text + "'", tes);
        byte[] barrImg = (byte[])cmdSelect.ExecuteScalar();

        if (barrImg != null)
        {
            string strfn = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToFileTime());
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(strfn,FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
            fs.Write(barrImg, 0, barrImg.Length);
            fs.Flush();
            fs.Close();
            tes.Close();
            pboxGAMBAR.Image = Image.FromFile(strfn);
        }
        else
        {
            pboxGAMBAR.Image = null;
        }

        tes.Close();
}
```

Comment: You dont need to create an intermediate file and one using a date string will not work,  You can create a bitmap from the `byte[]` read.  No "trick"

Answer (score 0):

private void btnCARI_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                tes.Open();

```
            //Retrieve BLOB from database into DataSet.
            Com = new SqlCommand();
            Com.Connection = tes;
            Com.CommandText = ("select gambar from tblBARANG where no=@no");
            Com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@no", Convert.ToInt32(txtCARI.Text));

            var da = new SqlDataAdapter(Com);
            var ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "tblBARANG");
            int count = ds.Tables["tblBARANG"].Rows.Count;

            if (count > 0)
            {
                var data = (Byte[])(ds.Tables["tblBARANG"].Rows[count - 1]["gambar"]);
                var stream = new MemoryStream(data);
                pboxGAMBAR.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
            } 
            tes.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
    }
```

Error, parameter  is not valid